# Player Y location messed up

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a resizable canvas in which a player is drawn. For some reason, the player will go off screen if the screen is too tall. This usually occurs in fullscreen mode, where the game will mostly be played. I've tried to change how it's calculated based on `mx` and `my`, but nothing seems to work.

Fullscreen, where the bug is happening: https://editor.p5js.org/Voxel_/full/61_2FX_-4

Code (it works fine in the preview canvas): https://editor.p5js.org/Voxel_/sketches/61_2FX_-4

Comment: You must add the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: I've never used p5 before, but try changing your `300 * mx` to just `300`. It looks like it works when you're using the ideal co-ordinate system, rather than the scaled real co-ordinate system.

Comment: I may be wrong but I see window.innerWidth but your canvas isnt the size of the window. so if your judging on an entire window of course the bird is going off the canvas. you need to make sure your canvas is always the entire screen. but also most importantly just width and height off of the canvas not the window. because canvas can be smaller than the window in this case its the p5 website